# Why is honey more viscous than water?

Tags: viscosity

Why is honey more viscous than water? And, if we boil honey to just below its boiling point, will it become equally viscous as water at normal temperature? How does changing temperature affect viscosity?

Answer (score 4):

Viscosity generally decreases with increasing temperature so honey will become less viscous at higher temperatures. Regarding the actual values, look at [this article](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0001-37652014000200981&script=sci_arttext&tlng=es). It appears that even at quite high temperatures honey remains a couple of times more viscous than water.

I think the reason for higher viscosity in honey is the high sugar () content - hydroxyl groups in sugars can form strong, hydrogen-bonded interactions with water and each other, and the sugar molecules being quite long, they are difficult to shear.